Auto-Create multiple RBD-pools using rook-ceph possible?
Maybe somebody here can help me out - the microk8s / rook-ceph docs don't really mention this properly: does microk8s connect-external-ceph support multiple pools?
I have created 2 pools on my microceph-cluster (1 being replicated, the other one being 2-1-EC). When connecting that ceph-cluster to my k8s using the following:
sudo microk8s connect-external-ceph --no-rbd-pool-auto-create --rbd-pool ssd
everything runs fine, the cephcluster is being connected and a storage class is being created:
Name:                  ceph-rbd
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           <none>
Provisioner:           
Parameters:            clusterID=rook-ceph-external,
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.comcsi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name=rook-csi-rbd-provisioner,csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace=rook-ceph-external,csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype=ext4,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name=rook-csi-rbd-node,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace=rook-ceph-external,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name=rook-csi-rbd-provisioner,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace=rook-ceph-external,imageFeatures=layering,imageFormat=2,pool=ssd

As seen, the pool ssd is correctly being used.
Now I would like to also connect my second pool mass_storage. But when I re-run sudo microk8s connect-external-ceph --no-rbd-pool-auto-create --rbd-pool mass_storage, I do encounter an error:
secret rook-csi-rbd-node already exists
secret csi-rbd-provisioner already exists
storageclass ceph-rbd already exists
Importing external Ceph cluster
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot re-use a name that is still in use

I expect this would come from rook-ceph trying to re-create the "ceph-rbd" storage class.
Now how should I handle this? Is there a way to specify the sc being created (e.g. ceph-mass_storage in my case)? Or would I need to manually create an SC in rook as described in the rook-docs here? Help would be much appreciated.
